# Remove line containing X & 20 lines above

Tags: php, macros, notepad++

I have a large text file I am trying to sort.

I need to:

1. Search for lines that contain 'No'
2. Delete this line and 28 lines above it

The document contains 6,1711 lines hence me looking for a quick way to do it.

Tried using Notepad++ but cant seem to be able to select the 28 lines above to also delete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `(.+\R){28}.*\bNo\b.*\R`
Replace with: `Nothing`

Make sure you've checked `Regular Expression` and NOT `dot includes newline`

If you want to restrict the search, you could use:

Find what: `(.+\R){28}.*\bemails: No\b.*\R`
Or every string that's more significant.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!

Sadly that just highlights the entire doc, it looks like the search didn't match correctly.

The full line is:

promotional emails: No

I tried to modify the above Find but it again didn't work, any other ideas?

Many Thanks,

Comment: What version of NPP are you using?

Comment: Thanks - I am using 6.1

Comment: @user3332692: Well I don't know if it's a version problem but I've tried here with 6.5.5 and it works fine. May be change the `\R` by `[\r\n]+`

Comment: Thanks, updated to latest version and still no joy. 

I'm using:

(.+\R){28}.*\bNo\b.*\R 

How would I add make it so it searches for 'emails: No' as maybe its matching too much?

Comment: Sadly still no joy - it just highlights the entire doc

Answer (score 0):

here's something to work on, read file into an Array loop through each line while incrementing index and 20 lines before it then save to new document the array.

```
 //read file into string array
$filelines = file('Filelocation.txt');
$i = 0;
foreach ($filelines as $line => $filelines) 
{
   if (strpos($line,'No') !== false) 
    {
      $j = $i
      while ($j > $i - 20) {
       unset($filelines[j]);
       $j--
       }

}
$i++;

}
//Save Whatever is left into new file
print($filelines)
```

Comment: This will also remove lines that contain `Nobody`.